Join Two 100k table taking longer than half hours
I am using pyspark to join two tables with 100k rows for each (so not skewed join). It takes longer than 30mins even an hour which I think something is wrong here. The code is just regular join
a = b.join(c, b.id == c.id, "inner").drop(c.id)

I did a lot search and try, including:

use more cores in cluster
replace larger instances in each node
set spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true
repartition etc

Neither works.
My question is: if both tables (pyspark.sql.dataframe object) came from using udf, does it matter? This is the only difference compared with common use.
I used the following udf logic to prepare the tables:
def func(row):
    id = row.split(",")[0]
    f1, f2 = ", ".join(row.split(",")[1:-1]), int(row.split(",")[-1])
    return (int(id), f1, f2)

func_udf = udf(func, 
              StructType([
                StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
                StructField("f1", StringType(), True),
                StructField("f2", IntegerType(), True)
               ]))
df = df.withColumn("Result", func_udf(col("data")))
df = df.drop(df.data).select("Result.*")

df is the table used for join.
Any troubleshooting idea is appreciated. Thank you.
P.S. table b has 3 columns and table c has 6 columns. So they are not
wide. Also, if I shrink size to 10k, the join works as expected.

Can you show all the logic that before the join and also show the action that trigger the execution? Yes, it's completely different in performance perspective comparing UDF VS Spark API

I figured out. I would like share my experience below:

For my case, I join tables first and later parse columns using UDF.
Certainly the table with UDF parsed show poor performance to
join (as pointed out by Jonathan below, using spark API could be a better option).
Even though the tables do not have many columns, but some data in columns is super big (long string). This also impacts the join performance.
Seems df.cache() is helpful.
Checking Logical plan is a good idea to check too.


Can you mark a response as the answer if you figured this out?

can you elaborate how to mark a response? Thanks.

If all those changes that you tried before didn't work, you can try to improve by using the Spark API but not using the UDF, as it will have data serialization and deserialization between Python runtime and JVM, and it affects the performance. In fact, your UDF logic can be changed to below:
df = df.withColumn(
    "data_split", 
    func.split(func.col("data"), ",")
).withColumn(
    "result",
    func.struct(
        func.col("data_split").getItem(0).cast(IntegerType()).alias("id"),
        func.concat_ws(", ", func.slice(func.col("data_split"), 2, func.size(func.col("data_split"))-2)).cast(StringType()).alias("f1"),
        func.col("data_split").getItem(-1).cast(IntegerType()).alias("id").alias("f2"),
    )
).select(
    "result.*"
)


Thanks. I will try it. What if the func is more complicated than just parsing a string? does it still work (from your experience)?

@TripleH It depends on the customized function, for example, if you need to use the external library, it's inevitable to use UDF. A rule of thumb is to try to use Spark API first,

a.explain()

check Logical Plan about b join c
